# Angular directive testing; click on an element does not trigger click on document

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, rxjs, observable

I have created a directive that it detects whether there has been a *mousedown* event **outside** the element that it is attached too. It is done with an observable:

```
 @Output() clickOutside = new EventEmitter<void>();

 constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

 ngOnInit() {
    this.eventSubscription = fromEvent(document, 'mousedown')
      .subscribe((event: MouseEvent) => {
        if (!this.elementRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
          this.clickOutside.emit();
        }
      });
  }
```

I am trying to write a test (jasmine) for it, I created a test component with the following template:

```
<div class="container" clickOutside></div>
<div class="another"></div>
```

When I mock a click on the .another element, there is a spy on on `this.clickOutside.emit()` that is expected to have been called, which is not the case. My test looks like this:

```
spyOn(directive.clickOutside, 'emit');
elementWithoutDirective.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('mousedown'));
fixture.detectChanges();
expect(directive.clickOutside.emit).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

This doesn't work as expected and the test fails with *Expected spy emit to have been called.*

The test works if

```
elementWithoutDirective.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('mousedown'));
```

is replaced with

```
document.dispatchEvent(new Event('mousedown'));
```

My assumption is that the click doesn't bubble up the event to the document. How can I model this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right regarding your assumption:

> the [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event) constructor creates an event that does not bubble by
>   default.

To change this behaviour you can pass second [eventInit](http://%7B%22bubbles%22:true) parameter:

```
new Event('mousedown', {bubbles: true})
```